# Sum of squares using generating functions

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, problem-solving, generating-functions

I tried using generating functions to solve the sum of squares formula based on the recurrence $a_n = a_{n-1} + n^2$ with $a_0 = 0$.

$$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n \\
G(x) - 0 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_{n-1} + n^2) x^n \\
G(x)  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n-1}x^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 x^n \\
G(x)  = x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^n + (-0^2x^0 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2 x^n) \\
G(x)  = xG(x) + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2 x^n \\
G(x)  = xG(x) + \frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3} \\
G(x) =  \frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^4} \\
G(x) =  \frac{0}{(1-x)^1} + \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{3}{(1-x)^3} + \frac{2}{(1-x)^4} \\
G(x) =   \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} - 3\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} + 2\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}
$$

Once I get to a spot like this I am unsure how to proceed. What is the smart way to solve the rest of this if you haven't seen a particular type of generating function before?

Comment: How do you know what the generating function for the sequence $n^2$ is? The techniques that lead you to that are just as suitable here.

Comment: @πr8 I don't know if it's a valid technique 100% of the time, but I took the derivative and multiplied by $x$ starting off from $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$

Comment: Yep, that applies here still. If you look at the derivatives of $\frac{1}{1-x}$, they'll give you precisely the type of terms you're looking for.

Comment: The derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$ is $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n x^{n-1}$ but then we have $n-1$ going negative at $n=0$ and I'm not sure how to correct this without multiplying both sides by $x$, which changes the lefthand side away from the form I want it.

Comment: Re-index: The term in front of $x^j$ is going to be $(j+1)$ (take $n=j+1$).

Comment: But isn't that the same as $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+1)x^{n}$? Don't you need the $n=0$ term for the closed-form generating function to be valid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34016/discussion-between-r8-and-aruka-j).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating functions - deriving a formula for the sum $1^2 + 2^2 +\cdots+n^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584854/generating-functions-deriving-a-formula-for-the-sum-12-22-cdotsn2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is convenient to obtain the coefficients already from
\begin{align*}
  G(x)=\frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^4}
  \end{align*}

> Using the *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a generating series we get
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^n]G(x)&=[x^n]\frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^4}\\
> &=[x^n]x(x+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-4}{n}(-x)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\left([x^{n-2}]+[x^{n-1}]\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+3}{3}x^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{n+1}{3}+\binom{n+2}{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}(n+1)n(n-1)+\frac{1}{6}(n+2)(n+1)n\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[binomial series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and $[x^n]x^kG(x)=[x^{n-k}]G(x)$. We also use the binomial formula $\binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k=\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}(-1)^k$

> Since
>   \begin{align*}
>   G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2\right)x^n
>   \end{align*}
>
> we conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)\qquad\qquad n\geq 0
> \end{align*}

*Hint:* You might also be interested in an *[operator based approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584854/generating-functions-deriving-a-formula-for-the-sum-12-22-cdotsn2/1585461#1585461)*.