# Find the sum of n terms of the series $1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+5^2-6^2....n^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I could just solve it by taking any value of n and plugging them in in the options. If n=3, then the sum will be 6, which is given by 
$$\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$$
My problem, the answer given is $\frac{-(n)(n+1)}{2}$. I doubt it’s validity, but I need to get it verified nonetheless.

Second, how do I derive it using the proper method.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $1^2-2^2+3^2-\ldots+n^2$?

Comment: the function $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=1+2+3+...+n$

Comment: Try $(-1)^{n-1} \frac {n(n+1)}2$ - clearly the sums alternate in sign.

Comment: Two cases if $n$ is even or odd.  If you are giv $1^2 - 2^2 + 3^2 - .... + n^2$ then $n$ is implied to be odd.

Comment: @Aditya in order to catch other's attention for sure, one should give enough number of terms in a sequence. Here one has to assume that it is an alternating series.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc it is an alternating series. However, I will add more numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're looking for $S(n):=1^2-2^2+3^2-\dots\pm n^2.$ If $n$ is even, note that we can group the sum as $$\begin{split}(1^2-2^2)+(3^2-4^2)+\dots+((n-1)^2-n^2)&=(1+2)(1-2)+(3+4)(3-4)+\dots+((n-1)+n)((n-1)-n)\\ &=-(1+2)-(3+4)-\dots-((n-1)+n)\\ &=-\frac12n(n+1).\end{split}$$
On the other hand, if $n$ is odd, we can still perform the same manipulations as above. Eventually we will end up with the formula
$$-\frac12n(n-1)+n^2=\frac12n(n+1).$$

Comment: I think you mean $-\frac{n}{2}(n-1)$ in the even-$n$ case, so the odd-$n$ case is $-\frac{n-1}{2}(n-2)+n^2=\frac12\left(n^2+3n-2\right)$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, thanks for catching that. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Could u explain the odd number of terms?

Comment: @Aditya note that $(n-1)$ is even, so we may apply the formula we derived for the even case to see that the first part of the sum is $-n(n-1)/2$. Then we add the $n^2$ term, so we have a $+n^2$. Simplifying yields the formula.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: So the final formula is $\frac12(-1)^{n+1}n(n+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Using generating functions, the ordinary generating function for the sequence $\{(-1)^{k+1}\}_{k=0}^\infty$ is $-1/(1+x)$, so the o.g.f. for the sequence $\{(-1)^{k+1}k^2\}_{k=0}^\infty$ is $$g(x) = -\left(x\frac d{dx}\right)^2\frac1{1+x} = {x(1-x)\over(1+x)^3}$$ so $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = [x^n]{g(x)\over1-x} = [x^{n-1}]\frac1{(1+x)^3} = (-1)^{n-1}\binom{n+1}2 = (-1)^{n-1}{n(n+1)\over2}.$$ (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1584854/265466) for an explanation of how this generating function is derived.)

It looks like you’ve either misquoted the given solution or there’s a typo in your source: the signs of the successive sums alternate.

Answer (score 1):

Well if $n$ is even then

$(2k-1)^2 - (2k)^2 = 4k^2 - 4k+1 - 4k^2 = -4k+1$ and

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n=2M} (-1)^{k+1}k^2 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^M[(2k-1)^2-(2k)^2] =\sum\limits_{k=1}^M(-4k+1) = -4\frac {M(M+1)}2 + M = -2M(M+1) +M = -2M^2-M=-M(2M+1)=-\frac {n(n+1)}2$.

And if $n$ is odd then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n=2M+1} (-1)^{k+1}k^2= -M(2M+1) + (2M+1)^2 = (2M+1)(M+1) = n(\frac {n-1}2 +1)=\frac {n(n+1)}2$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

You have the wrong formulae.

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$

And also note that $$-\displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^\frac n2 (2i)^2 = -4\displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^\frac n2 i^2$$